# ASP.NET User Control inner content

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control which accepts a title attribute. I would also like that input inner HTML (ASP Controls also) inside of that user control tag like so:

```
<uc:customPanel title="My panel">
     <h1>Here we can add whatever HTML or ASP controls we would like.</h1>
     <asp:TextBox></asp:TextBox>
</uc:customPanel>
```

How can I achieve this? I have the title attribute working correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: i think you cant do this... But yo can do it in .ascx of ur user control

Comment: Can you specify a bit please? I have <%=title%> and <%=content%> in my ascx file which works fine, but it's a pain to pass custom HTML to the content property.

Comment: System.Web.UI.UserControl doesnot have a property textbox

Comment: You can dynamically add controls to your user control

Comment: Why aren't you putting these tags and such inside the user control's own (ascx) file? Or is this a custom control instead of an actual user control?

Answer (score 7):

Implement a class that extends Panel and implements INamingContainer:

```
public class Container: Panel, INamingContainer
{
}
```

Then, your CustomPanel needs to expose a property of type Container and another property of type ITemplate:

```
public Container ContainerContent
{
    get
    {
       EnsureChildControls();
       return content;
    }
}
[TemplateContainer(typeof(Container))]
[TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
public virtual ITemplate Content
{
    get { return templateContent; }
    set { templateContent = value; }
}
```

Then in method `CreateChildControls()`, add this:

```
if (templateContent != null)
{
    templateContent.InstantiateIn(content);
}
```

And you will be using it like this:

```
<uc:customPanel title="My panel"> 
    <Content>    
        <h1>Here we can add whatever HTML or ASP controls we would like.</h1>
        <asp:TextBox></asp:TextBox>
     </Content>
</uc:customPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure EnsureChildControls is called. There are number of ways of doing that such as through the CreateChildControls base method but you can simply do this to get the inner contents of a custom control to render. It gets more complicated when you need to remember state and trigger events but for plain HTML this should work.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
    EnsureChildControls();
    base.Render(writer);
}
```