# Is it possible to define a one-off user control in the ASPX codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0, webusercontrol

One of my big beefs with ASP.NET is that it makes it difficult to organize the controls of a page beyond excessive amounts of prefixing IDs. I have gone to great and complicated lengths in the past to try to alleviate this, but I would like a solution that is easier to implement. So, I'm wondering:

Is it possible to define a user control in the codebehind of a .aspx, and then use it in the .aspx? I'm thinking probably not... I can't get it to work.

Comment: Perhaps you simply want to look into "ASCX" user controls?

Comment: I knew of those already, I was just wondering if there was another way of doing it that could be more self-contained. But at the same time, keeping a complex page all in one file might not be the greatest idea. I think I'll just have to settle for using public usercontrols and put them inside of the same namespace as the page that uses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You must create a user control in it's own .ascx file.

Though if you wish wish to create a web control, you can define that in whichever .cs/.vb file you want. Though for the sake of your coworkers being able to find your code, I might suggest it live in it's own file anyways.

NOTE: I would question the validity of "it difficult to organize the controls of a page beyond excessive amounts of prefixing IDs". This is what templated controls (repeater, datalist, etc) are for. They will implement [`INamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx) and thus will enable you to name controls with the same name, but different scope. There's some good info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671712/how-to-implement-a-custom-panel-with-inamingcontainer/3671788#3671788)...

Answer (score 0):

There has to be an existing ASP.NET user control defined, and you can dynamically load it.  That's about as much as dynamic capabilities with user controls that you have.  You can also leverage custom controls, which really gives you the complete control over the rendered UI.  However, not rendering complete ID's can have subsequent issues with the client/server integration, depending on what you are trying to do.

Also, to customize the ID, you can leverage ASP.NET 4.0's ClientIDMode property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx